# Bug in Data Explorer - Incorrect user name shown

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm being logged into Data Explorer as “jon.doe18”, why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53569/im-being-logged-into-data-explorer-as-jon-doe18-why)
>   [Wrong user when logging into Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

This is the first day I joined Data-Explorer. I logged in using my google open id, and it showed logged in as `jon.doe7929` . That is not me. But somehow it displayed my pic correctly.   Is it some kind of eater egg or actually a bug ?

[image]

Comment: believe me, it is your self only, with a unique id of stackexachange.