# Known StackExchange OpenID receives jon.doeXXXX username at data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I'm being logged into Data Explorer as “jon.doe18”, why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53569/im-being-logged-into-data-explorer-as-jon-doe18-why)

I logged into [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for the first time, using the same OpenID that I use on ServerFault and throughout the network. StackExchange clearly recognized my identity (and applied my photo to the profile), but my username was set to `jon.doe8020` instead of `Miles Erickson`.

Possibly relevant: I reached data.stackexchange.com for the first time via [sysadmin1138's link](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/892/old-seriously-unloved-questions) from [Cleaning house, really old, unloved questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1210/cleaning-house-really-old-unloved-questions).

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. Data Explorer doesn't share the account system with the rest of Stack Exchange. Photos are pulled from Gravatar, so if you used the same email address, it'd get identified correctly.

Feel free to edit your profile to set the name and whatnot, but it won't be linked to the rest of your accounts.

Comment: Thanks. If this is by design, would it make sense for some explanatory text to be displayed at first login?

Comment: @MilesErickson I'm not sure there's a real expectation that the accounts *would* be linked, since SEDE isn't a Q&A site within the network.

Comment: @AnnaLear Neither is Careers. Or Area51. Or MSO, if you're feeling pedantic. Plus, it's hosted on a subdomain of stackexchange.com

Comment: @lunboks True enough. (Although MSO is a bad example, and I am feeling pedantic. :))

Comment: @AnnaLear Bottom line: it's confusing and inconsistent, violating [the basic principles of UX design](http://uxmag.com/articles/guiding-principles-for-ux-designers), e.g. "acknowledge that the user is not like you" and "be consistent."

Comment: @AnnaLear It's confusing as hell. I'm so used to getting my profile on any *.stackexchange.com site that I was sure I had done something wrong. Only by reading this answer did I realize its by design.