# Make it possible to merge user accounts in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, openid, merge-accounts

[This is my profile in Data Explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/8439/hims056) I logged in there with Gmail account which I am using in Stack Exchange. So my user id of any Stack Exchange site is automatically populated there. I have three open id in my Stack Exchange profile. (Gmail, Facebook, and MyOpenId). I don't use Gmail account for login in Stack Exchange (Because I always logged-in in my office with my office's Gmail account). So I use Facebook/MyOpenId for login there. [But there is no option to login with Facebook in Data Explorer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141685/187824) So I login with MyOpenId. But it created a new profile there. And there is no option to merge my both open-id (Gmail & MyOpenId) in Data Explorer. While changing openid it shows the following error message:

> Another user with this OpenID already exists, merging is not possible at this time.

Why is merging not possible in Data Explorer?

<sub>Related: [I'm being logged into Data Explorer as "jon.doe18", why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53569/im-being-logged-into-data-explorer-as-jon-doe18-why)</sub>

Comment: Just a thought.. the Data Explorer is [open source project](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) so guess the Stack Exchange developers don't want to give *too many* options in there. (i.e. through the API)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I forget why this was a concern before (it might have been from before the user merging queries were written), but the current reason is just that it hasn't been implemented. Strictly speaking, merging users *is* possible in Data Explorer, it's just not set up yet to do it automatically in the case you're describing.

I've got a todo item to make sure it's safe to add the necessary code, so I'll look into it later this week when I get back from my vacation.

Comment: Great! Should I re-tag it with `feature-request`?

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable

Comment: A side question: Why do you not have a moderator sign (♦)?

Comment: Well, I'm not a moderator or an employee :P

Comment: @Tim but you can add such sign to [yourself](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/4836/tim-stone) on Data Explorer, right? ;)

Comment: @TimStone: You probably _should_ be one _somewhere_. You get my vote when MSE comes out ;-)

Comment: After two years of campaigning _to_ Mr Stone that he should run, Josh and I have run out of convincing him. Best of luck to all you trying to get him to run, I don't see it happening ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand If I could be a Meta diamond I'd be all over that. Also FWIW SEDE has diamonds too, which I assume was what he was referring to :P

Comment: why oh why does SEDE have diamonds? ... I suppose to moderate the queries and ensure folks are behaving nicely?

Comment: @jcolebrand There are some mod tools like merging users and the like, yeah. Also moderating comments if that finishes being implemented and deployed.

Comment: Wait, there's comments on SEDE now? Apparently I really need to go look at all that then...

Comment: @jcolebrand Just in a local branch on my computer :P

Comment: @TimStone - Is your vacation over?

Comment: Is the implementation of this feature possible in *near* future?

Comment: @hims056 Yes. I'm not sure why I didn't get to it before, but I will do something about it before Monday.

Comment: @TimStone - Okay. Looking forward. But will the Data Explorer be [updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178288/187824) after you implement it?

Comment: @hims056 It shouldn't take too long for it to be updated, no. But I don't have an exact timeframe.

Comment: @hims056 Just as a heads up, I did put some time into this...will finish testing later today and get a pull request sent out.

Comment: @TimStone knock knock :)

Comment: @TimStone knock knock knock.

Comment: Any progress on this?