# "contact us" link in Data Explorer site is outdated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

For a while now, the "contact us" link in the footer or every Stack Exchange site points to `http://[site]/help` (e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) which is all  good.

However in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) site it's still the good old `mailto:team@stackoverflow.com`.

There are other links missing in the footer, but that's a different issue and not a big deal.

(Marking this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as it's not really a bug but require manual changing of code)

Comment: There's a lot of SEDE that would benefit from being brought into an SE 2.0 "shell" if it were.

Comment: Where should this point? SEDE doesn't have a `/help` page...if you want one, what should go on it?

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Anything in particular? :P

Comment: @Tim good point! Guess the help form here on Meta is most suitable.

Comment: @TimStone Tags and comments are the first things that come to mind, for easy categorization as well as feedback.  Deletion of queries as well.  Of course, this means you need moderation of some sort, so I know it's not exactly a small request.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Ah, [this may be relevant to your interests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160143/why-merging-accounts-is-not-possible-in-data-explorer/160144#comment464123_160144). Tags are on the wish list too, but some there's some issues around who gets to create tags and the like, and then the moderation issues you mentioned.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, I know it's not easy, but ask, and get an answer =)

Comment: Hopefully a lot of that will be up and coming though, since it's stuff I'd like to have too :P

Answer (score 1):

As part of [this pending pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/12), I cleaned up the Data Explorer footer. The "contact us" link now points to the [same place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) as the one here on Meta does, since that seemed like the most appropriate target.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know when it's deployed. :-)