# Please merge SEDE accounts, normal options unavailable

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid, myopenid

Original SEDE account ID: 6306
Newly added account ID: 11949

**Please allow my Stack Exchange OpenID on account 6306, and discard/merge account 11949.**

---

MyOpenID is not working anymore for the *Stack Exchange Data Explorer* (SEDE), even though [it is theoretically available until February, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/148310).

So, I logged in via my Stack Exchange, OpenID account -- but it created a new SEDE account for me instead of using my old one.

Given:

1. [There is still **no provision for automatic, or user-driven merging** of SEDE accounts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160143/148310)
2. The **normal [Support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)** contact for merging accounts **does not accept `data.stackexchange.com`** profiles.

It seems the only recourse we have for merging SEDE accounts is to post on Meta?  And, [the Meta post technique has worked before for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88744/148310).

---

Also, is there an update on [the previously linked status request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160143/148310)?
Thanks.

Comment: As I was trying to say before (previous version of this question was deleted); what about team@stackexchange.com. I thought an email was the fastest way to get merging done

Comment: P.s. both of your point 2 links 404

Comment: @RichardTingle, Fixed the one stale link; all others still work.  And no, for any other site, you would use the Help Center contact (linked in the Q).  But there is not one for SEDE.